# possible to do this in 1 line

Tags: php

I have a function that returns an array of named values `['upper','lower','chosen']`. To read the `upper` value, I do this

```
$returned = myfunction($input1, $input2);
$upper = $returned['upper'];
```

Is there any way to get it all done in 1 line, maybe like this, but this syntax doesn't work. Any other way?

```
$upper = myfunction($input1, $input2)['upper'];
```

Comment: You could always [upgrade to PHP 5.4 which adds array dereferencing support.](http://www.php.net/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
 list ($upper, $lower, $chosen) = myfunction($input1, $input2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function could return an object instead of an array. Then you could do something like this :

```
class myObject {
    public $upper;
    public $lower;
    public $chosen;
}

$upper = myFunction($input1,$input2)->upper;
```

Answer (score 2):

If upper is always the first element, you can use [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php):

```
$returned = array_shift(myfunction($input1, $input2));
```